# Why isn't this Do Form valid?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to Common Lisp. I tried out the following do form:

```
(do ((n 0 (+ n 1)))
    (< n 10)
    (print n))
```

Clisp responds with:

```
*** - IF: variable < has no value
```

From my understanding, the do form is as follows:

```
(do (<lexically scoped variables> [per-iteration-expression])
    (end-expression)
    <statements>)
```

Where's the error in my understanding of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgive me, my Lisp is rusty, but shouldn't that be a `>`?
And then shouldn't it be `((> n 10))`? (Two parens, not one. You need something evaluated there).

This could be completely wrong, but that would be my next try.

Comment: Actually, that's correct. It just now clicked that the end form takes a series of expressions, not just one. Also, I'm not used to loops terminating when their expression tests true. It's all very new for me. Thank you!

Comment: It's a bit strange, but Lisp is such an awesome language despite its (what now looks like) quirks.

Comment: I've been at it for a while. This is by far the trickiest language I've ever learned, but I want to be a member of this strange cult. ;)

Comment: If it really advanced my career, I would study Lisp perpetually, but I don't see a common use of it. Granted, I've not studied Clojure (a Scheme dialect) yet

Comment: @cwallenpoole Clojure is not a Scheme dialect.

Comment: @Matthias I've seen a lot of people say that it is.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Yeah, if it wasn't a fairly common misconception, I wouldn't be bothering dispelling it. :)
For a (very inexhaustive!) list of technical differences between Scheme and Clojure, see: http://clojure.org/lisps

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.n-a-n-o.com/lisp/cmucl-tutorials/LISP-tutorial-18.html) (random Google search result), the second term should be `((end-expression) return-value)`.